# iOS Core data: How to setup delete rule in relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two models: **Course** and **Student**. 
Each **student** can have several **Courses** (to-many), and each **Course** can have several **students** (to-many)

How do I setup the delete rules between then so:

- When deleting a **student**, the **Course** should only be deleted if no other students is in it.

Comment: if you are deleting the student a, then you need to delete only relationship between the student and course.. if you need to delete course if no students are mapped, then you need to check the student(NSSet) relationship of the course whether it contains any other students object. if no students delete the course.

Comment: Would you not want to keep the course in case you need to add students to it later on?